# Synonym - "to go above someone"

Tags: synonyms

What's a synonym, preferably solely in one word? I tried [circumvent](http://thesaurus.com/browse/circumvent) and its synonyms (eg bypass, sidestep, ...), but still desire a better one. [Example](http://books.google.com/books?id=3KH3cUj_8tUC&pg=PA94&dq=%22go+above+the+teacher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BcKhU9GZF4_18QXIsIHgBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22go%20above%20the%20teacher%22&f=false):

> If you decide to **go above** the teacher, always tell the teacher your
>   intention and that you're unsatisﬁed with the outcome of the situation.
>   Principals will loop back to the teacher before they respond to you
>   99 percent of the time so it only hurts your relationship if you go blindly
>   around the teacher. Use words that are professional and positive as sug-
>   gested later in this chapter.

Comment: The usual phrase is "go over someone's head", which extends the vertical organization chart metaphor by including body parts in the chart.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try *escalate.* If you decide to *escalate* the issue, always tell the teacher....

Comment: But _escalate_ simply means 'increase the conflict level', without specifying any bureaucratic process.

Comment: A more formal way of expressing it is "appeal to a higher authority".

Comment: @ Prof Lawler: Is that right? Doesn't *escalating an issue* imply someone is seeking restitution from a higher-up in a hierarchy? https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22+escalate+the+issue%22

Comment: 'surmount' and 'supersede' are also within the right semantic neighbourhood, and could be of interest in a differently phrased sentence.

Comment: "Go over the teacher's head" sometimes implies going /directly/ to a higher authority, or without permission.  If you tried to work things out with the teacher, didn't get the result you were looking for, and then told the teacher that you were going to ask the principal about it and the teacher said OK, I don't know if that expression would fit.

Comment: Escalating doesn't necessarily include going up a level in the hierarchy, as you can escalate an issue by simply drawing more attention to the issue. Also, **obviate** is another word that is in the neighborhood.

Comment: We're not getting closer to a single word, so far, aside from *circumvent*. As for multiple-word expressions, there is also *go around*: *She went around her management to get support from the head of another department.*

Answer (score 1):

I think that *escalate* is probably the most common one-word term for this action, at least in the United States.

Merriam-Webster Online continues to offer the same definitions of *escalate* that it has used since the verb (a back formation from *escalator*) debuted in the Eighth Collegiate Dictionary (1973):

> *intransitive verb*:  to increase in extent, volume, number, amount, intensity, or scope (a little war threatens to *escalate* into a huge ugly one — Arnold Abrams)
>
> *transitive verb*:  EXPAND 2 [that is, "to increase the extent, number, volume, or scope of :  ENLARGE"]

Neither of these definitions fits the poster's case. However, as Autoresponder hints in a comment above, *escalate* has also been used since at least 1969 in the specific sense of "take [an issue] to a higher-level authority on appeal," which appears to be precisely the sense that the poster has in mind. Why Merriam-Webster hasn't acknowledged this particular meaning of *escalate* after not less than 45 years of consistent usage in published writing is a mystery to me.

From [Hearings, *Reports and Prints of the Senate Committee on Labor and Public Welfare*](http://books.google.com/books?id=mhE2AAAAIAAJ&q=%22escalate+the+issue%22&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zb7yU6iiGcXZoASvoIGoAQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCQ) (1969) [snippet]:

> In at least four of the above instances, the Regional Director upon disagreement with the Regional Legal Services Director may institute appeal procedures which **escalate** the issue in dispute to the National Director of the Legal Services ...

From Frederick Mosher & John Harr, [*Program Budgeting Visits Foreign Affairs*](http://books.google.com/books?id=-k4vAAAAYAAJ&q=%22escalate+the+issue%22&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zb7yU6iiGcXZoASvoIGoAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA) (1969) [combined snippets]:

> He would depend on the arts of persuasion, having little power to force the issue. His only recourse if rebuffed would be to **escalate** the issue up the chain of command in State. Short of the Secretary (and Under Secretary), no one in State had real authority to force an issue with another agency. Naturally, few desk officers would take this route except in the rare case in which they were dealing with a vital policy matter ...

From [*Riots, Civil and Criminal Disorders: Hearings Before the Senate Committee on Government Operations*](http://books.google.com/books?id=v6o2f9XhxnEC&q=%22escalate+the+issue%22&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2cfyU9LBBKWIjAL01oGAAw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBjgK) (1969) [snippet]:

> Senator JAVITS. It occurs to me and my people, Dr. Abram, you may find the right course because I am interested in the procedure. I, too, will be against Federal law creating new criteria, but I do think there is something to be said for a remedy in the Federal courts which does **escalate** the issue to a higher judicial level.

From *[Proceedings of the Federal Management Improvement Conference](http://books.google.com/books?id=xIrHbDWnTqIC&q=%22escalate+the+issue%22&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zb7yU6iiGcXZoASvoIGoAQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw)* (September 21 and 22, 1970) [combined snippets]:

> When an issue arises, employee representatives are inclined to engage in a "shopping around" tactic by approaching various management officials regarding the issue. They "shop" until either they get the answer they want or have so many different "official" views that they can **escalate** the issue to higher authority. There is nothing so embarrassing to management or so useful to a labor organization than to get two or three "official" and conflicting positions on an issue.

These examples strongly suggest that this particularly sense of *escalate* arose in U.S. federal government jargon; but it has since spread to business (and elsewhere) while remaining common in government work as well. From Stewart Liff, [*Managing Your Government Career: Success Strategies That Work*](http://books.google.com/books?id=qpenJ34MDIUC&pg=PA137&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MMzyU9j6CcfsoATExIKgDA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22escalate%20the%20issue%22&f=false) (2009):

> If you are not satisfied [with a supervisor's response to a complaint], you then have two options: Either drop the issue or pursue it further. If you decide to **escalate** the issue, give your supervisor the courtesy of knowing that you plan to go over her head. While she may not like it, at least she will not be caught off guard. Pursue the complaint as professionally and unemotionally as you can; simply state the facts, indicate why you feel aggrieved, and identify the remedy you are seeking.

And from Michael Bender, [*A Manager's Guide to Project Management: Learn How to Apply Best Practices*](http://books.google.com/books?id=zHPVTc0nte8C&pg=PA148&dq=%22escalate+the+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MMzyU9j6CcfsoATExIKgDA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22escalate%20the%20issue%22&f=false) (2009):

> The purpose of the control limits is to signal when the project is in trouble. Classically, when the cost variance percentage or schedule variance percentage crosses  the inner control limit, the project management team must take action. If either variance percentage crosses the outer control limit, the project manager must **escalate** the issue to senior management. The location of the control limits varies among organizations and project categories.

In none of the examples above does *escalate* refer to increasing the magnitude of a conflict; rather, it refers to appealing a lower-level decision about a conflict to a higher-level authority. In that respect, the connection to the noun *escalator* seems quite rational. I should perhaps also note that, although all of the examples reproduced here are from Google Books search results for "escalate the issue," Google Books finds similar (though not as early) results for "[escalate the matter](http://books.google.com/books?id=gTQ4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22escalate+the+matter%22&dq=%22escalate+the+matter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V9byU6mtN6bHiwKr1oCIDg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA)," and "[escalate the dispute](http://books.google.com/books?id=B0Lwc6ZEQhcC&pg=PA197&dq=%22escalate+the+dispute%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oNjyU6SBCIfYigLdroHgBA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22escalate%20the%20dispute%22&f=false)."

If you do decide to use *escalate* in the context of an appeal to a higher hierarchical level in a dispute with a teacher, you'll be using the word in a now-common way. (Note that the verb *escalate* in any sense has been around only since 1944, meaning that the "raise to a higher level in an organization" sense appeared within 25 years of the word's first sighting, and has enjoyed increasingly widespread use during the 45 years since 1969.) Specifically, you might frame the relevant sentence as follows:

> If you decide to **escalate** the matter to someone who is above the teacher in the school hierarchy, always tell the teacher your intention and that you're unsatisﬁed with the outcome of the situation.